# How do I retweet messages with a specific hashtag with tweepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I followed this guide, but this isn't working for some reason. It says that they are retweeted, but I don't see the retweets on the bot account.

```py
import tweepy
import json
from time import sleep
# from credentials import *

with open('config.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(config['consumer_key'], config['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(config['access_token'], config['access_token_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=('#philzafanart -filter:retweets'), lang='en').items(100000000):
    try:
        # Add \n escape character to print() to organize tweets
        print('\nTweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name)

        # Retweet tweets as they are found
        tweet.retweet()
        print('Retweeted the tweet')

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

wait i messed up, ignore this. It was retweeting from my main account because i forgot to update the keys, fun